# Home Networking Setup with AT&T UVerse

Tags: home-networking

I have U-Verse with AT&T. I would like to implement some family controls on it, e.g., content control and shutting it down after a certain time of night, but the Uverse router doesn't have  any of these features.

I could conceivably plug another router into the wireless router, but then the UVerse wireless router is still broadcasting, and I'm not sure if there's a router-level content control solution.

Anyhow, I'm a programmer with a screwdriver, so I would appreciate some input.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I too have U-Verse and can confirm some of their routers do not let you turn off the Wi-Fi.

The simplest solution is just set a long complicated password for the wireless and never use the password on any of your devices. You then instead connect to the wireless of your new router that contains parental controls.

(You are on your own for finding another router that has parental control features. You may want to look in to [custom firmwares](http://www.techspot.com/guides/416-wireless-router-custom-firmware-alternative/) that have more features than stock firmwares)